# centering an img within a div - both being resized

Tags: jquery, css, html, resize

I'm trying to center a resized image within its container (which should also be centered). I don't understand why this is so difficult, but I've been trying to get this working for 7 hours now. Please help :-)

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
function imageresize() {
var conHeight = ($(window).height())* 0.56; 
    $(".resize").css({'height' : conHeight + 'px'}); // set large-image container to 56% of window height
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  imageresize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  imageresize();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation-area">
    <div id="navigation">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="set-overflow">
    <div class="resize" id="large-image">
        <img src="images/bg-home.jpg" class="resize">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
/*------------------------------*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation {
    width:990px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin:23px auto;
    height:42px;
}
#navigation-area {
    width:100%;
    height:135px;
    background:url(images/bg-navigation.png) top center no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:-3px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50%;
    z-index:50;
}
#large-image {
    width:1970px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-985px;
    left:50%;top:0;
    z-index:40;
    display:block;
}
#set-overflow {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:20;
}
.resize {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

I need the overflow:hidden on the containing div as this will eventually be a single-page scrolling site and the large image is required only in the first div scrolled to. The image needs to be 56% of the viewport/window.

Please let me know whether I need to clarify anything.

MTIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZgWg/26/

Let me know if that's not what you're looking for and we can tweak it together.

Comment: Really close, but the image should remain in proportion. Proportion of image is approx height:width 1:4.

Comment: K, fixed and updated link.  I got rid of that large-image div, if you add it back just keep its style neutral and you're set.

Comment: It almost works! It's working perfectly on browser resize, but not on document load, which I don't understand.

Comment: What browser? looks fine to me in all the browsers I've tried.  Are you talking about your code or the jsfiddle?  I was deleting properties and style definitions in the fiddle that you might've missed.

Comment: I've updated my code again just to be sure. The jquery seems to work on document load in FF, but not Safari or Chrome (mac). The resizing works on all the browsers.

Comment: does the fiddle work in Chrome?  I'm on Chrome in Windows, that'd be pretty weird if it doesn't work for you on a mac.

Comment: the fiddle does indeed work in Chrome. I've taken all the css, jquery & html from the fiddle. So can't understand why it's not working on document load in Chrome & Safari.

Comment: well it sound like you have some extra code or styling that's making it do something different on load.  Try to simplify the style, just take out what you don't need like I started to.

Comment: there's no extra code or styling. it's as is in the fiddle. I've checked the element on load (w = 1004) in Chrome and get the following:  <img src="images/bg-home.jpg" class="resize" style="height: 258.16px; margin-left:502px;">.

Comment: on resize, (w = 973), <img src="images/bg-home.jpg" class="resize" style="height: 236.32px"; margin-left: 4.5px;">

Comment: oh interesting, the imageResize must be firing before the img has any width.  Because look, 502 is 1004/2 which means $('#set-overflow img').width() is 0.  You can alert that on load to confirm.

Comment: Absolutely. So is there a timeout or something I can use so it waits until the width is set?

Comment: Well, that's what $(document).ready() is for.  If you do alert(left); does it alert twice?  In what order?

Comment: no, just once on document load if I add the alert to the function.

Comment: It should be $(document).ready() like in the fiddle.  Load is before the DOM is ready, just after all the HTML was downloaded.

Comment: okay, i've put all the jquery refs after </body>, which I guess I should've done before heh, and it's working after a short delay in which the img resizes. i'm going to go die now. thank you so much for your help - i appreciate it so much.

Comment: @circey - just thought of something while I was sleeping.  Putting the script outside the </body> tag does not validate.  You can achieve the same effect by putting it right *before* the </body> tag.  But if you put it inside `$(document).ready(function(){ *HERE* }`, you should be good too, it sounded like you were using document.load which is not right.

Comment: I had a thought too. I've changed the css for the img to display:none, then added '.show()' to the end of the img resize code. Works much better as the user doesn't see the resize effect. As you suggested, I've moved the script inside the </body> tag and it still works fine in all browsers. I *was* using document.ready - not document.load - I was just too tired to know the difference! Many thanks again :-)