# How to set background image to keep its position while browser width is changing?

Tags: css, background-position, browser-width

I am wondering how I could set the background image to keep its position on this site: http://www.jylkkari.fi/wordpress/

When you drag the browser under 960 px wide, the background of sidebar starts to move towards center.

I found out [this Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809784/move-background-image-based-on-browser-width) which could solve this problem.

I am still searching if there is a easy way in CSS to keep the image centered while browser width is more than 960 px and on fixed while it is under this size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.......................... Define your body

```
min-width:980px;
```

---

```
body{
min-width:980px;
}
```

--------------for ie

used to ie condition css as like this

```
 <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**create a css file**

```
body{width:980px;}
```

more info about ie css ***[click here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)***

Comment: I got it, but there is time limit going on.

Comment: You should be careful where you want to use min-width. In IE it's not supported. You should set width also in case you're going to show the page in IE<8.

Comment: Do you have any advice, how to make it for the IE<8?

Answer (score 0):

Do this by adding `width: 960px;` to the element the background statement is on (in your case this would be `body`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media query, to change the CSS of the body when it reaches a certain width:

```
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    background-position: left center;
  }
}
```